# Error when performing Hough circle transformation on OpenCV-python

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

The code below is intended to perform a Hough Circle transformation on a video. The code works as intended when a frame from the video is extracted and an Hough Circle transformation is performed. However, when I try to replicate the similar method to produce a video I get this error `loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type NoneType which has no callable rint method`. The cause of this error seems to be below the while loop. What could be the cause of this issue?

Many thanks in advance.

Update: I have changed my `blurred = cv2.medianBlur(dframe, 25)` to `blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(dframe,(11,11),0)`. This seem to work for a moment but then the code crashes to give me the same error.

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

np.random.seed(42)

def fixColor(image):
    return(cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    
video = cv2.VideoCapture("video.wmv")

#randomly select frames in an array 
frameIds = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) *np.random.uniform(size = 55)

#store selected frames in an array 
frames = []
for fid in frameIds:
    video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT,fid)
    ret, frame = video.read()
    frames.append(frame)
    
video.release()

#calculate the median frame
medianFrame = np.median(frames,axis=0).astype(dtype=np.uint8)

#random sample 
sample_frame = frames[0]

#convert to grayscale
grayMedianFrame = cv2.cvtColor(medianFrame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
graySample = cv2.cvtColor(sample_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#subtract grayscale frames between sample and median
dframe = cv2.absdiff(graySample, grayMedianFrame)

blurred = cv2.medianBlur(dframe, 25)
#plt.imshow(fixColor(blurred))

#Hough circle 
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blurred, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,120,param1= 50, param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

for i in circles[0, :]:   
    # draw outer circle
    cv2.circle(sample_frame, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)
    # draw center of circle
    cv2.circle(sample_frame, (i[0], i[1]), 2, (0, 255, 0), 9)

plt.imshow(sample_frame,cmap="gray") #outputs image from sample frame with Hough circle

#write in new video
writer = cv2.VideoWriter("output_hough.mp4",cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MP4V"),30,(512,512))

video = cv2.VideoCapture("video.wmv")
total_frames = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)

frameCnt = 0
 
########## CODE WORKS FINE UNTIL THIS POINT ##############

while(frameCnt < total_frames-1):
    frameCnt +=1  
    ret, frame = video.read()  #read frame 1 by 1 
    
    gframe = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #grayscale frame
    dframe = cv2.absdiff(gframe, grayMedianFrame)  #remove background
    blurred = cv2.medianBlur(dframe, 25)  #blur
  
    #Hough transformation
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blurred, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,120,param1= 50, param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    
    for i in circles[0, :]:   
        # draw outer circle
        cv2.circle(frame, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)
        # draw center of circle
        cv2.circle(frame, (i[0], i[1]), 2, (0, 255, 0), 9)

    writer.write(cv2.resize(frame,(512,512))) #write frame into output vid
    
video.release()
writer.release()
```

Comment: Did you already do some debuging? If so, please tell us if `blurred` is correct before you do the HoughCircles.

Comment: I believe the image you are trying to use does not exists. Check your images with imshow() or .shape to be sure it exists at each stage of your processing.

Comment: @not_a_bot_no_really_82353 yes, the first part of the code shows that `blurred` works fine.

Comment: @fmw42 I check that in the first part of the code. It seems to work well but when I repeat in through the while loop that's when the problem occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not show the full stack and the exact line that is throwing the error.
But, looking at your code I guess the problem lies in:

`circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))`

What happens is that `cv2.HoughCircles` can return `None` if it can not find circles, then `np.around` is not working with None.

What you should do is check first that you got your circles by `if circles is not None:`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. How do I bypass this issue?

Comment: like I wrote, check if you got `None` and do what you want to do when there are no circles. ex: skip this frame, by `continue` or leave the frame as it is by performing only the `writer.write`

Comment: Adding `if circles is None:
        continue`  after the line `circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blurred, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,120,param1= 50, param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)` seems to have solved the problem. Thank you very much!